# Issues with scraping images on a Node JS server using Puppeteer after deployment on Render

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, chromium, infinite-scroll

I have a server where, after sending a POST request using Puppeteer, I open a page, scroll down to the bottom, and only then return the HTML code of the page. My aim here is to send all the URLs of images because they load in an infinite scroll manner. Locally, everything works as it should, meaning it returns all the images from the page. However, after deploying on Render, the request only returns 3 images. Could the reason for this be limited access to RAM memory (512MB) in the free version of the server?

This is my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
const { port } = require('./config');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mime = require('mime')
const cors = require('cors')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

// fix cors
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './')));

// headers
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000'); // Dostosuj '*', aby zezwalać tylko na konkretne domeny
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  next();
});

// disabled buffor
app.disable('etag');

// mime
mime.define({
  'application/json': ['json']
}, { force: true })

// pasery
//Content-type: application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

function scrollToBottom({
  page,
  distancePx,
  speedMs,
  scrollTimeoutMs,
  eltToScroll,
}) {
  return page.evaluate(
    (distancePx, speedMs, scrollTimeoutMs, eltToScroll) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const elt = document.querySelector(eltToScroll);
        let totalHeight = 0;
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
          const scrollHeight = elt.scrollHeight;
          window.scrollBy(0, distancePx);
          totalHeight += distancePx;

          if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            resolve();
          }
        }, speedMs);

        setTimeout(() => {
          clearInterval(timer);
          resolve();
        }, scrollTimeoutMs);
      });
    },
    distancePx,
    speedMs,
    scrollTimeoutMs,
    eltToScroll
  );
}
 

const scrollAndGetPageHTML = async (req, res) => {
  // Set up Chromium browser and page.
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: [
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--single-process",
      "--no-zygote",
    ],
    executablePath:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        ? process.env.PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH
        : puppeteer.executablePath(),
  });

  try{
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    //default timeout to navigation-related function(goBack(), goForward(), goto(), reload(), setContent(), waitForNavigation())
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    // //default timeout tto navigation function and waiting function(waitFor(), waitForFunction(), waitForRequest(), waitForResponse(), waitForSelector(), waitForXPath())
    page.setDefaultTimeout(0); 
    // Navigate to the example page.
    await page.goto(req.body.url);
  
    await scrollToBottom({
      page,
      distancePx: 200,
      speedMs: 50,
      scrollTimeoutMs: 10000,
      eltToScroll: "body" 
    })

    const html = await page.content();
    res.send(html);
  } catch (error){
    console.error(error);
    res.send(`Something went wrong! Error: ${error}`);
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
};

app.post('/htmlCode', scrollAndGetPageHTML);


// server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

I installed all dependencies using Dockerfile on Render.

How I can send all image url on production to my website?